# WSL2 internet and ping not working

Tags: wsl2

What can I do when internet is not working in ubuntu WSL (Windows 10)? I can't ping any IPs or domains from WSL, with 100% packet loss. curl google.com also doesn't work. Domain name resolution with nslookup works with the default nameserver in resolv.conf (which starts with 172), but not with 8.8.8.8 or 1.1.1.1.

I also used netsh reset commands, restarted my pc, and disabled Windows firewall, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WSL2 cannot access the internet on Windows 11](https://superuser.com/questions/1691097/wsl2-cannot-access-the-internet-on-windows-11)

Comment: @harrymc No, I've tried netsh reset commands, changed nameserver in resolv.conf and also disabled the firewall.

Comment: It should work if done right.

Comment: Can you please list the outcome of each of the steps in the suggested duplicate? Right now evidence indicates the same symptoms mean the same problem, and the same problem requires the same solution. Simply telling us it isn't so does not SHOW that it isn't show.

Answer (score -1):

I experienced this issue in Windows 11, and found that I had to create a Hyper-V switch (external) and specifically set the VLAN tag for the management OS in order to get WSL distros connected.