# Ubuntu installed in WSL can NOT reach the Internet

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

Asked before by other people.  I used the answers to their questions to get a head start, but still no joy.

My software mix:

```
Windows 10 Enterprise

WSL version: 2.0.14.0
Kernel version: 5.15.133.1-1
WSLg version: 1.0.59
MSRDC version: 1.2.4677
Direct3D version: 1.611.1-81528511
DXCore version: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows version: 10.0.19045.3803

Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
```

The relevant files:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
#Cisco VPN IP
nameserver 10.8.8.8
$

$ cat /etc/wsl.conf
[network]
generateResolvConf = false
[automount]
options = "metadata"
$
```

After doing all of that I exited out of Ubuntu and WSL. I then ran wsl --shutdown and started over with a fresh PowerShell

ping google.com still fails.

```
~$ ping google.com
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

ping 8.8.8.8 just hangs

```
$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
153 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 158057ms

$
```

I also rang a ping on 10.8.8.8 and 10.8.8.4, the name servers for my Cisco VPN.  Both just hung:

```
~$ ping 10.8.8.8
PING 10.8.8.8 (10.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 10.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
17 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 16631ms
$
```

I also tried pinging my gateway, no joy:

```
~$ ping 172.19.48.1
PING 172.19.48.1 (172.19.48.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 172.19.48.1 ping statistics ---
17 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 16619ms

~$
```

Here is my "ip route" output:

```
$ ip route
default via 172.19.48.1 dev eth0 proto kernel
172.19.48.0/20 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 172.19.59.151
$
```

Is there anything else I can to get Ubuntu to reach the Internet while I have the Cisco VPN running?

Comment: What is the ping error ? Is `google.com` correctly resolved by the DNS ?

Comment: Please add more information in your post with the `routes table`, the `ping` error output and the `IP` of your machine. Thanks

Comment: try `ping 8.8.8.8`

Comment: I see you're using Cisco VPN. Can you give more details about your usage of it.

Comment: @hidigoudi by routes table do you mean the output of ipconfig /all ?
I updated my post with the ping error.

Comment: @harrymc all I do with Cisco VPN is connect at the start of the day to reach company resources.

Comment: The nameserver is `10.8.8.8`, can you ping it on the host?

Comment: For routes : `netstat -r` or `ip route`

Comment: @harrymc ping 10.8.8.8 just hung.  I updated my post with the output.

Comment: @hidigoudi I ran ip route, the output is now on the bottom of my post. Thank you.

Comment: Are you able to ping `172.19.48.1`, this is your gateway. If no, this may explain your problem.

Comment: See [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1691097/wsl2-cannot-access-the-internet-on-windows-11) and try the proposed solutions.

Comment: @hidigoudi  I updated my post with the output for pinging my gateway.  That just hanged too.